# ClickOnce deployment in VB.NET - launch online only error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I have been trying to fix this problem for a long time. When I fix one issue another one pops up. I am pretty sure I am on the last hurdle though.

I have an application I want to make available to users online. A click launches it, and it downloads and runs from the download cache. This is an option in Visual Studio 2010 ClickOnce deployment.

When I first uploaded the files through FTP to the webserver I had issues with the file extensions, the webserver was not recognizing them. I was able to add the correct [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) types to the htaccess file and, success, the application almost launches..

I am getting the same `application cannot be started error` with the details below,

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
   Windows                     : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
   Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.296
   System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
   clr.dll                     : 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
   dfdll.dll                   : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
   dfshim.dll                  : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCE
   Deployment url              : http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest8 /Application%20Files/snake_1_0_0_6/snake.application
   Server                      : Apache

IDENTITIES
   Deployment Identity         : snake.application, Version=1.0.0.6,   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5bd57d3abffa2377, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
   * Online only application.
   * Trust url parameter is set.

ERROR SUMMARY
   Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
   * Activation of http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest8/Application%20Files/snake_1_0_0_6/snake.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
   No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
   There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
   * [27/04/2013 2:29:49 p.m.] : Activation of http://apps4you.comyr.com/appTest8/Application%20Files/snake_1_0_0_6/snake.application has started.
   * [27/04/2013 2:29:50 p.m.] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
   * [27/04/2013 2:29:50 p.m.] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
   Following errors were detected during this operation.
   * [27/04/2013 2:30:07 p.m.] System.Net.WebException
    - The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri,    ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
        at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String   role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenAndPush(Uri uri)
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.PushExternalEntityOrSubset(String publicId, String systemId, String baseUriStr, Uri& baseUri, String entityName)
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
        at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()
        at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
        at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
        at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
        at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
   No transaction information is available.
```

So the launch of the application is looking promising, but it's still not there. What could this internal server error (500) be? I have done some research, and it seems pretty generic. What do the details in the stack trace mean?

Comment: So I redeployed the application and I am no longer getting the error (500) I am one step a head now. I now get the error  "+ Downloading http://apps4you.comyr.com/apptest/Application Files/snake_1_0_0_9/snake.exe did not succeed.
  + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." I have changed the mime type so it forces the download of the exe file, I have checked the file is there. What the heck is wrong ???

Comment: final resolution to my problem - I also need the MIME type - AddType application/octet-stream .exe added into the htaccess file.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please write the solution into answer and accept your own answer. That will make browsing the question a lot easier.